# PHP Directory Scope

Tags: php, html, debugging, path, navbar

I'm facing a pretty particular problem, basically I'm tryng to create an header in my PHP project. I put my navbar into the "View" folder, and I'm including it with require in each page that I need to use it, I do the same thing with my head, that includes stylesheet and other stuff... Basically the problem is when I try to call the head/the navbar all the relative paths that I used in my 2 files get messed up, since when I call them I'm into another folder. I found three different solutions, and the one who seems to be the best doesn't work.
(I would rather not to use js, if there's any other good solution)

1 Solution that I tried:
I used absolute PATHS, it works, but it doesn't seem right to me, first of all, the file is not going to work in other computers, but only in mine, and it doesn't seem to be a correct approach to the problem. (But then I thought about creating a constant that contains the path of the folder which contains the project, but there's a problem, how do I make that constant to be accessible from every single file in the project? Since when I create it, it's not global.

2 Solution that I tried:
This one is kinda tricky, I basically tried to make a function that generates the entire navbar

```
    <?php
include_once(PATH.'/functions/relpath.php');
function getNavbar($currentPage, $isInsert, $inserimenti){
  $navbar = "
  <nav class='navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
      <a class='navbar-brand' href='#'>Libreria</a>
      <button class='navbar-toggler' type='button' data-bs-toggle='collapse' data-bs-target='#navbarsExampleDefault' aria-controls='navbarsExampleDefault' aria-expanded='false' aria-label='Toggle navigation'>
        <span class='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
      </button>
  
      <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='navbarsExampleDefault'>
        <ul class='navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0'> ";
    if($isInsert){
      //Nel caso in cui ci troviamo in una pagine di inserimento
      $pathhome = getRelativePath($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],PATH.'/index.php');
      $pathtabella = getRelativePath($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],PATH.'/src/tabelle.php');

      $navbar.= "
      <ul class='navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0'>
      <li class='nav-item'>
        <a class='nav-link' href='".$pathhome."'>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class='nav-item'>
        <a class='nav-link' href='".$pathtabella."'>Tabelle</a>
      </li>
      <a class='nav-link dropdown-toggle active' href='#' id='dropdown01' data-bs-toggle='dropdown' aria-expanded='false'>Inserisci</a>
      <ul class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdown01'>
      ";
      foreach($inserimenti as $key => $value){
        $relpath = getRelativePath($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],PATH.'/'.$value);
        $navbar.= "
        <li><a class='dropdown-item' href='".$relpath."'>".$value."</a></li>
        ";
      }
      $navbar.="
                </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          </nav>
      ";
    }else{
      //Nel caso in cui ci troviamo in un altra pagina, non di inserimento
      $pathhome = getRelativePath($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'/progetti/www/Informatica/Marzo2021/ProgettoLibreria/index.php');
      echo("PHP SELF: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\n PATH ABS: ".PATH.'/index.php'."\n Path Generata da Funzione ".$pathhome);
      $pathtabella = getRelativePath($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],PATH.'/src/tabelle.php');
      if($currentPage=="index.php"){
        $navbar.= "
        <ul class='navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0'>
        <li class='nav-item'>
          <a class='nav-link active' aria-current='page' href='".$pathhome."'>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class='nav-item'>
          <a class='nav-link' href='".$pathtabella."'>Tabelle</a>
        </li>
        <a class='nav-link dropdown-toggle' href='#' id='dropdown01' data-bs-toggle='dropdown' aria-expanded='false'>Inserisci</a>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdown01'>
        ";
      }else{
        //Dovrebbe quindi essere la tabella

        $navbar.= "
        <ul class='navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0'>
        <li class='nav-item'>
          <a class='nav-link' href='".$pathhome."'>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class='nav-item'>
          <a class='nav-link active' aria-current='page' href='".$pathtabella."'>Tabelle</a>
        </li>
        <a class='nav-link dropdown-toggle' href='#' id='dropdown01' data-bs-toggle='dropdown' aria-expanded='false'>Inserisci</a>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdown01'>
        ";
      }
      foreach($inserimenti as $key => $value){
        $relpath = getRelativePath($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],PATH.'/'.$value);
        $navbar.= "
        <li><a class='dropdown-item' href='".$relpath."'>".$value."</a></li>
        ";
      }
      $navbar.="
                </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          </nav>
      ";
    }
    return $navbar;
}

?>
```

In this function, I call another function that I copied from another guy that essentially, outputs the relative path if you give to it the absolute path of your current folder, and the absolute path of the folder that you want to go to. As follows

```
<?php
function getRelativePath($from, $to)
{
    // some compatibility fixes for Windows paths
    $from = is_dir($from) ? rtrim($from, '\/') . '/' : $from;
    $to   = is_dir($to)   ? rtrim($to, '\/') . '/'   : $to;
    $from = str_replace('\\', '/', $from);
    $to   = str_replace('\\', '/', $to);

    $from     = explode('/', $from);
    $to       = explode('/', $to);
    $relPath  = $to;

    foreach($from as $depth => $dir) {
        // find first non-matching dir
        if($dir === $to[$depth]) {
            // ignore this directory
            array_shift($relPath);
        } else {
            // get number of remaining dirs to $from
            $remaining = count($from) - $depth;
            if($remaining > 1) {
                // add traversals up to first matching dir
                $padLength = (count($relPath) + $remaining - 1) * -1;
                $relPath = array_pad($relPath, $padLength, '..');
                break;
            } else {
                $relPath[0] = './' . $relPath[0];
            }
        }
    }
    return implode('/', $relPath);
}
?>
```

The third solution is the one that I thought to be the best pick, basically I wanted to use the function chdir(), to change the working folder. Essentialy, when I'm into a file that is inside a folder i use the command chdir('..') in order to get into the main folder, and then I could use the relative paths as if I was out of that folder. Put apparently it doesen't work as planned at all, since it still doesn't work!! The relative paths inside the head and the navbar act as if they where into a folder, even if the working folder changed... I'm desperate at this point.

[This is the page inside a folder, don't minnd the paths that I wrote, it's for debug, but as you can see, it doesn't load the css that is inside the head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls19s.png)

And when I click on a link of the navbar, it acts like I'm into a folder
[when I click home, it should go into index.php, but out of the folder, not inside src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTPiH.png)

The last thing that I send is the folder structure that I have, It's not complete, but at least you can see the interested part. Consider that the navbar and the head is into the view file, while the pages of the website are into src
[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sba7U.png)

If you need more details about the problem, or anything else, ask me. Thanks in advance for the help, if you have other solutions apart from solving the ones that I tried, it would be very nice, I'm sorry if I made some grammar mistakes or anything else, since my spaghetti Italian English could be a bit rusty.

Comment: considering your "global" path the main project folder, when you want to reference a file from inside a dir you can go to the global using ../ and then using the path to the file you want to reference.
For example this structure:
Project > folder1 > file1.css
  and   
Project > folder2 > file2.php
             
In file2.php you can request file1.css by writing "../folder1/file1.css" because ../ means "go up" in the dir path

Comment: Well, yes I know that, but the problem is, if I put the dots always, when I'm out of a folder this is not going to work, like if I'm into the index file

Comment: Uhm so I didn't get what the problem is...are you requesting an html header file that requests a style file inside?

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710831/passing-parameters-to-php-include-require-construct

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't put my question in the right way. I have two files, the header and the navbar, inside this two files I use some relative paths. I want to include this two files inside every single page of my site, the problem is, the file works perfectly fine as long as i''m into the main folder, when I get into another folder, like the folder that contains all the pages of the site it doesen't work, since the relative paths are messed up.

Comment: That's why of the link I posted before; consider to use a function that require the navbar file and take as input the path. Than in the navbar file you use the path input to change it where you need it. But it's just an idea...

Comment: Mh, that could work, I'll give it a try, thanks :)